# Xamarin Forms Navigation stack errors when automatically pushing a page after retrieving data from an API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms page that retrieves data from an API and then automatically pushes another page. This works the first time, but in subsequent calls, it pushes the newly created page as well as the page created in the last round onto the view hierarchy.

Like so:

First use:
pushPage1

1. page1 loads data
2. page1 automatically pushes page2 (first instance)
3. page2 displayed properly
4. page stack is rootPage->page1->page2(first instance)
5. popToRoot

Second use:
pushPage1

1. page1 loads data
2. page1 automatically pushes page2 (second instance)
3. page2 (first instance) displayed first
4. page2 (second instance) displayed second
5. page stack is rootPage->page1->page2(first instance)->page2(second instance)

If I don't push automatically and I wait for user input to push page 2 I don't get this unexpected behavior. I still get it if I add a delay after receiving data from the API.

Edit: I have tracked this down further to the use of the messaging center. My page push operation is triggered by the messaging center. However, I am invoking on the main thread like so:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get through, just saying you get an error is a bit vague!!!

Comment: Hi , you can share the code of second scene . And not too much understanding why need to navigate to page2 second times .

Comment: @FreakyAli Maybe I shouldn't describe it as an error since there is no error message or exception. An unexpected behavior would be more correct. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @meursault334 *rootPage->page1->page2(first instance)->page2(second instance)* this logic is strange .

Comment: Are you using Prism to navigate?